# SQL Query for MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

```
Table:skill
SkillID int(10) unsigned
Description varchar(100)

Table: question
QuestionID int(10) unsigned
SkillID int(10) unsigned
Details varchar(100)
```

There are many rows in the question table for each skill. I want to run one query listing all skills and only one question for that skill (does not matter which question).

How can that be done?

Comment: what if a particular skill has no equivalent in question table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOR **MYSQL AND SQLSERVER**

```
SELECT * 
FROM skill S 
INNER JOIN question Q ON S.SkillID=Q.SkillID 
INNER JOIN (
SELECT SkillID ,max(QuestionID) QuestionID
FROM question
GROUP BY SkillID)T
ON S.SkillID =T.SkillID AND Q.QuestionID=T.QuestionID
```

FOR **MYSQL**

```
SELECT SkillID ,max(QuestionID) QuestionID
FROM question
GROUP BY SkillID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT SkillID, QuestionID -- or, whatever fields you would need
FROM question
GROUP BY SkillID
ORDER BY RAND()
```